# how to select a particular drop down option element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use this function to work on all my drop down lists. Problem: the first drop down works okay, but hen I try select any option in the 2nd drop down selections. It places the value from the first group in the span of the second group. I want the span to have the value from its own group. I would like to use this on multiple groups.

```
  <script>function displayResult(xspan,xselect)
{
 var x=document.getElementById(xselect).selectedIndex;
 alert(x);
 var newTxt = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;

 document.getElementById(xspan).innerHTML = newTxt;
 //alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option").length);
}
</script>

<select id="myPhones" onchange="displayResult('ShowPhone','myPhones')">
    <option value="">Phone  Numbers</option>
    <optgroup label="Shipping">
        <option value=" - 800-463-3339">FedEx</option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<span id="ShowPhone"></span>

<select id="myParts" onchange="displayResult('ShowParts','myParts')">
    <option value="">Qik Parts list</option>
    <optgroup label="BATT">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
        <option value="2"><1/option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<span id="ShowParts"></span>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for displayResult() ?

Comment: Where is the fracking `displayResult` function? Are we supposed to guess what it contains, or just create a new one for you without even knowing what it does ?

Answer (score 1):

Chage the id and the displayResult of the second dropdown:

First dropdown:

```
<select id="myPhones" onchange="displayResult('ShowPhone','myPhones')">
```

Second dropdown:

```
<select id="NewNameID" onchange="displayResult('ShowPhone','NewNameID')">
```